# SQL Query to filter rows using a sub query which queries the same table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, subquery

I am trying to build a query which filters rows based on other rows as in the following example

```
TableA

Id    status        type       date
300   approved      ACTIVE    11/12/2015 10:00:00
300   approved      ACTIVE    11/12/2015 10:10:00
300   approved      INACTIVE  11/12/2015 11:00:00
200   approved      ACTIVE    11/12/2015 11:10:00
200   approved      INACTIVE  11/12/2015 11:10:00
100   approved      ACTIVE    11/12/2015 11:10:00
```

From the above table I am trying to return Ids that have equal number of ACTIVE and INACTIVE types like Id 300 has two rows with type ACTIVE and one row with type INACTIVE, so Id 300 should be excluded from my results where as 200 has 1 active and 1 inactive and it should be included in the results

In the above table status, type can have other values too but I care only the ones listed above ignoring others

So, for TableA final result of the query would be

```
Id
200
```

I tried to run the below query but that didnt give me the results I expected

```
SELECT Id
FROM TableA oa
WHERE oa.type in('ACTIVE','INACTIVE') 
and oa.status='APPROVED'
 and not EXISTS(SELECT
            x.id
            ,COUNT(*)
        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                id
                ,c.type
            FROM TableA c
            WHERE 
            AND c.type IN ('ACTIVE','INACTIVE')
            AND c.status = 'APPROVED'
            AND c.Id= ta.Id
            )x
        GROUP BY x.Id
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
```

**Can the above query be corrected to get the required results?**

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use `SUM` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT Id
FROM TableA 
WHERE 
    status = 'approved'
    AND type In ('ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE')
GROUP BY Id
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'INACTIVE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: Thank you and how do edit the query to also include id in the cases when ACTIVE s are greater than INACTIVES?

Comment: Change the last "=" to ">"

Comment: Use >= to include both.